# Decide on near zero eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, singular-values

I am using SVD to solve a homogeneous system of $N$ linear equations in $12$ variables, where $N \gg 12$, in the **least-squares** sense. In order to determine the null-space of the $N \times 12$ matrix, I need to pick out the eigenvalues which are zero. But in a numerical solution the eigenvalues are near zero, here an example of the $12$ eigenvalues for a sample $N \times 12$ matrix:

```
S = [ 15.2158 5.96262 5.53325 3.27387 3.03468 2.84257 0.683411 0.625499 0.20319 0.136146 0.0276132 0.00103614 ]
```

Because I am using known input/output pairs, I know that

```
[ 0.0276132 0.00103614 ]
```

are the two "zero" eigenvalues. However, in the general case, where does one put the threshold below which the eigenvalue is considered zero, especially when eigen values do not have a unit?

Comment: sorry... to be concise: if $A$ is the over-determined matrix, then SVD computes the eigenvectors/eigenvalues of $A^T A$... I am talking about these eigen values

Comment: Those are the squared **singular** values. Bad idea to use uppercase for both matrices and integers.  Are you using Matlab?

Comment: Usually you use a ratio, comparing the small singular values to the largest one. If you want to be a bit more careful you can compare the sum of the squares of the singular values you are discarding to the sum of the squares of those you are not discarding.

Comment: thanks for pointing the problem with the casing...no I am not using Matlab, rather the gnu gsl library

Comment: ... thanks also for suggesting the ratio. I will try that.. But seems somewhat adhoc. I cannot find an analytical treatment on the subject of how to deal with near-zero values in the case of numerical problem solving

Comment: Tolerances are usually more art than science.

Comment: Also hold on, how does this problem even make sense? A generic $N \times 12$ homogeneous system with $N \gg 12$ has a single actual solution, so why does it make sense to look at a least squares solution at all?

Comment: I am not sure why you say that the system has only a single solution. It all depends on how big the null space of the matrix is. In any case even if the system has rank=12 I believe that the least squares solution will find a vector of length 1 that is "closest" to all the hyper planes defined by the rows of the matrix? So there is a non-trivial solution

Comment: I'm just puzzled at where a $N \times 12$ matrix with $N \gg 12$ that has nontrivial null space is coming up. That is why I mentioned the word "generic"; you need a huge amount of linear dependence for a matrix like this to have a rank less than 12. At any rate, a least squares solution will always be a true solution if a true solution exists, and for a homogeneous system the trivial solution always exists.

Comment: What you are describing with discarding small singular values that are truly not zero (not just nonzero due to numerical error) is not least squares, but rather some kind of low rank approximation. That does actually do what you are describing, e.g. the right singular vector is a unit vector $x$ such that $\| Ax \|$ is as small as possible.

Comment: I meant to say the right singular vector for the smallest singular value.

Comment: the matrix arises from an image processing algorithm I am working on. Assuming that the coordinate system is centered at an arbitrary pixel in the image and given a  pixel $c$ near the origin, then the following holds ($\bf{m}$ and $\bf{u}$ are unknown $1 x 6$ vectors and $D_c$ and $P_c$ are known $6 x 6$ triangular and invertible matrices: \begin{equation}
\bf{m} = {\bf D}_c^{-1}\cdot {\bf P}_c \cdot{\bf D}_c  \cdot\bf{u}. 
\end{equation}.  In order to solve for $\bf{m}$ and $\bf{u}$, I set up the following homogenous system:

Comment: \begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
{\bf D}_1\cdot{\bf P}_1&  - {\bf D}_1\\
\cdots & \cdots\\
{\bf D}_n\cdot{\bf P}_n&  - {\bf D}_n\\
\end{bmatrix}_{(6n)\times 12}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
\bf{u}^{T} \bf{m}^{T}
\end{bmatrix}_{1\times 12}^T
=\bf{0}_{(6n)\times 1}^T
\end{equation}

Comment: an index $i$ in the block matrix above represents the $i$-th pixel in a neighborhood of the origin. Do you think that this is an abuse of the least-squares method? I do get some proper results in tests.

Comment: sorry, earlier I said that $\bf{m}$ and $\bf{u}$ are $1 \times 6$ vectors, I meant $6 \times 1$.

Comment: I would just pose the least squares problem of minimizing $\sum_c \| m-D_c^{-1} P_c^{-1} D_c u \|^2$, but some kind of constraint in the model rather than the method is required for this to not just be zero when $m=u=0$. Your constraint that $(u^T,m^T)^T$ is unit sounds arbitrary, from what you've said so far.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I will have to look deeper into your suggestion. It makes sense. I need look for an additional constraint in the model, as you suggest.

Comment: One question though: do you know the difference in terms of algorithmic complexity between what you suggest and my original version?

Comment: it is also know that if $c=(c_x, c_y)$ represents the coordinate of a pixel point, then $\bf{u}\cdot(1, c_x, c_y, c_x^2, c_x c_y, c_y^2) \geq 1$. Can I use that as a least-squares constraint?

Comment: Yes, with that you can set up an optimization problem that won't have a trivial solution.

Comment: ok... I will give it a try.

Comment: If you used the correlation matrix for eigenanalysis, the sum of the eigenvalues would be 12.   Then the two eigenvalues you selected would likely be much smaller.   In addition, using correlation, you could use a threshold of 1 for an eigenvalue cutoff, below which the dimension (principal component or eigenvector) generally represents noise.  Also, eigenanalysis is typically done on a square matrix (e.g. 12 $\times$ 12) which may or may not be symmetric.   The covariance and correlaiton matrices are square-symmetric.

Comment: I do not know about eigenanalysis, do you know a good online reference? Nonetheless I am somewhat confused how a unit-less quantity (the eigenvalue) can be used,  when the underlying problem (in this case a geometric one) produces matrix values that (albeit in a convoluted and nonlinear way) are related to the units in the geometrical space. My intuition says that the cutoff point for the eigenvalue needs to be related to a preset error (epsilon) in the geometric space and thus be related to the unit.